# Can I use google maps pins to populate a form on my webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-maps, dynamic

I have a database of **over 600 map markers** with `longitude` and `latitude` and all the applicable information for them to be used by the clients.

I need to create something that allows me to click the pin marker within the map and then any data attached to that pin *(phone number, postcode, address, etc)* to be pulled from that pin in the database and be added into the form.

Can I extract data from google maps to populate a form on the webpage?

Comment: The short answer is "yes". I had to type something longer because SO requires it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a "yes"/"no" question. Either you can easily test it yourself, or you already have a partial solution to show, with a problem to submit to the community, and then you can be helped :)

Comment: @kheldar if you look below someone has already helped with a solution. it isn't off topic by any means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to do certain steps for this.

Generate key from Google Developer :

Link = https://code.google.com/apis/console/

generated key = "GeneratedKey"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourGenerateKeyHere">
    </script>
<script>
 
   function getLocation()
    {
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 var address = document.getElementById("Location").value;
 var latitude = 0;
 var longitude = 0;
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
  showPosition(latitude, longitude, address);
 }
 }); 
   }
    function showPosition(latitude, longitude, address)
 {
  var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
          zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: address,
  });

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
     
</script>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="Location" placeholder="Type address here" />
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Click here to see map</button>
  
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find something useful [here:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)